# MeteorJS run script after reactiveVar change

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a helper that evaluates code from an input and shows it in a div. Now I would like to run a script after the `{{htmlMarkup}}` is rendered on the template.

```
Template.code.helpers({
    htmlMarkup:function(){
       $('#some-code').empty();
       return input.get();
    }
 });
```

The problem is that `Template.code.onRendered` is only called once when the page loads. How do I run code after the markup is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `Tracker.afterFlush` inside your template helper :

```
Template.code.helpers({
  htmlMarkup: function(){
    $('#some-code').empty();
    Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
      // your script goes here
    });
    return input.get();
  }
});
```